# React Admin: Select existing image or upload new

Tags: reactjs, image-uploading, image-gallery, react-admin

usually when working with images in an admin-panel you have the possibility to choose an existing image or to upload a new one. I wonder how this could be achieved with react admin.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to choose an existing resource or to create a new one "inline"? E.g this is a common pattern with Tags.
2. How would I approach the selection of an existing image? Using `ReferenceInput` with a custom renderer?

Answer (score 0):

For upload a new image you can use [`<ImageInput>`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#imageinput).

For select an existing image you need to create a custom implementation based on [`<ImageField>`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#imagefield).